# Rails transitive model association queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Edit: Assume A is "Forum", B is "Topic" and C is "Post".

Model A has_many B (B belongs_to A)

Model B has_many C (C belongs_to B)

Question: How to query directly as if Model A has_many C (and C belongs_to A)?

Comment: try using `A has_many C through B`

Comment: Please don't use fake values. They can be confusing, misleading or both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say your "A" is "Forum", your "B" is "Topic" and your "C" is `Post`.

**Forum**

```
has_many :topics
has_many :posts, through: :topics
```

**Topic**

```
belongs_to :forum
has_many :posts
```

**Post**

```
belongs_to :topic

def forum
  topic.forum
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Ryan Bigg is right with the [has_many :through (official documentation)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association), but i'd suggest to delegate the opposite side like:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foods
  has_many :recipes, through: :foods
end

class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :recipes
end

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :food
  delegate :category, to: :food
    allow_nil: true
end
```

Using Module#delegate is much more convenient compared to a delegating method and uses the syntactic sugar Rails offers. You also can set prefixes and stuff. Read about the law of demeter ([Do not break the law of Demeter!](http://chris-on-rails.blogspot.de/2014/08/do-not-break-law-of-demeter.html)) and the [Module#delegate API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) too.